# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord command handler and it is errors when checking if commands has it or something.

```js
let cmd = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();
let command;

if (client.commands.has(cmd)) {
    command = client.commands.get(cmd);
} else if (client.aliases.has(cmd)) {
    commmand = client.command.get(client.aliases.get(cmd))
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

Comment: Your client.commands is coming undefined. Where are you assigning the property client.commands?

Comment: client.commmands = new Collection();

Comment: oh i fixed it, there was an extra m

Comment: Rule 1, of JS development... Get an editor with some form of linting... :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at in `if (client.commands.has(cmd))` the `client.commands` is
`undefined`, so you can't get its `has` property. You can check the `client.commands` and declare the `client.commands` and ensure it's not `undefined`.